# I have a checkbox in a DataGridView that is not rendered/visible and can't be interacted with in some remote desktop sessions - how to I fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop, rdp, highdpi

### Environment

RDP Target: Windows 2016 Hyper-V Server

RDP Client: Windows 10

Main Monitor of client:  1920x1080 150% scaling.

### Application

C++/MFC with spawned (via COM) C# Winform, showing a Data Grid View with a number of controls, including checkboxes in cells.

C# .NET 4.6/4.7

### Problem

The Checkbox does not render at all when shown. Does not happen if the RDP target is a Windows 10 client in a local Hyper-V.

Using any monitor as the RDP session host which is not 100% or 125% exhibits the problem.
Problem happens at any resolution.

### Workarounds

- Using a monitor with 100% scaling, or 125% scaling.
- Inside the target server, set the application to use 8bit colour in compatibility mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the row height was fixed, and too small. The checkbox was unable to draw.

The following line of code solved it.

`grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;`

Comment: This was driving me insane, thanks for sharing the solution. I can imagine there are going to be lots of old WinForms apps still in production that will suffer from this problem...

Comment: you can also fix a number of these issues by using `mstcs.exe /dpiunaware`. A hidden command line option to the RDP client which forces no DPI awareness.